# calculate a column with the order of a date in other column

Tags: r, data.table

I want to do a simple task and can not figure out how.
I have a dataframe (data.table in fact) similar to this:

```
date         code1 
2015-03-01     A
2015-03-02     A
2015-03-03     A
2015-03-01     B
2015-03-02     B
2015-03-03     B
```

and I want a new column with the date order by code1 as follows:

```
date         code1   order
2015-03-01     A       1
2015-03-02     A       2
2015-03-03     A       3
2015-03-01     B       1
2015-03-02     B       2
2015-03-03     B       3
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: [datatable] or [data.table]?

Comment: In base R, `df$order <- unlist(lapply(split(df, df$code1), function(x){seq_along(x$date)}))`

Comment: dataframe transformed by the "data.table" package

Comment: or `unlist(tapply(df$date, df$code1, seq_along))`

Comment: ...or better in case they're not in order, `unlist(tapply(df$date, df$code1, rank))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `data.table`:

```
dt[, order := seq(.N), by = code1]

> dt
#         date code1 order
#1: 2015-03-01     A     1
#2: 2015-03-02     A     2
#3: 2015-03-03     A     3
#4: 2015-03-01     B     1
#5: 2015-03-02     B     2
#6: 2015-03-03     B     3
```

Comment: this is what is was looking for. it performed really fine in a >100 millon rows dataframe. thanks!

Comment: From the next version, it's also possible to do: `dt[, order := rowid(code1)]`.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(code1) %>%
   mutate(Order = row_number())
   date code1 Order
#      (chr) (chr) (int)
#1 2015-03-01     A     1
#2 2015-03-02     A     2
#3 2015-03-03     A     3
#4 2015-03-01     B     1
#5 2015-03-02     B     2
#6 2015-03-03     B     3
```

As @alistaire mentioned, if the 'date' column is not ordered, we can either use `arrange` to order by 'date' after the `group_by` and then create the sequence with `mutate` or use `rank`

```
df %>% 
  group_by(code1) %>% 
  mutate(Order = rank(date))
```

---

Or using a convenient wrapper from `splitstackshape`

```
library(splitstackshape)
getanID(df, 'code1')[]
```

---

Or with `base R`

```
df$Order <- with(df, ave(seq_along(code1), code1, FUN= seq_along))
```

Comment: In case they're not in order, it's probably safer to do `df %>% group_by(code1) %>% mutate(order = rank(date))`